# Add state to string, working with Strings

Tags: reactjs, string, typescript

I have an issue, just moved to typescript, and I dont know how to connect/add my state to string. I have two dependent dropDowns, so when I choose "organization", I want to send its "id" to 'departments'dropDown's apipath. Can you help me please, thank you.

```js
const SubDivision = ({ dynamicForm }: { dynamicForm: DynamicForm }) => {
  const [organizationId, setOrganizationId] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div>
      <h4 style={{ margin: 16 }}>asd</h4>
      <Grid>
        <GridRow>
          <GridCell span={12}>
            <Select<Organization>
              label="Organization name"
              api="/organization"
              required
              search
              type={Organization}
              onChange={(organization: Organization) =>
                setOrganizationId(organization.id)
              }
            />
          </GridCell>
        </GridRow>
        <GridRow>
          <GridCell span={12}>
            <Select<Option>
              required
              //defaultValue={dynamicForm.departmentHash}
              label="Department"
              type={Option}
              api="/api/v1/state_schedule/cells-list/?code=DEPARTMENT&code=INDEPENDENT_POSITION&organization_id=" //Thi is where I want to put organization.id
              defaultOptions={defaultOptions}
              //onChange={(value: Option) => dynamicForm.departmentHash = value}
            />
          </GridCell>
        </GridRow>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above snippet, you are assigning the organization using the method `setOrganizationId(organization.id)`. So, we can use the variable to which you are assigning this value in the mentioned function.

For eg: Suppose your function assigning the orgId to `selectedOrgId`

```
function setOrganizationId(orgId){
    this.selectedOrgId = orgId
}
```

then in your html code:
`/api/v1/state_schedule/cells-list/?code=DEPARTMENT&code=INDEPENDENT_POSITION&organization_id={selectedOrgId}`

Please note, I'm not sure what kind of template syntax you are using. Based on the framework or parser, make necessary changes in your solution. Here I used `{selectedOrgId}` just to demonstrate how we could read data.